# Javascript error in ASP.NET caused by changing from Cassini development server to IIS 7.5 express

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, cassini

I have recently changed from using the cassini development server to IIS 7.5 express, and have found that on some pages  my javascript is throwing 'Object doesn't support this property or method' exceptions.
 All the pages share the same masterpage which loads all the plugins, and when debugging in the browser the scripts seem to be available.
 One particular example is

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
    var dlg = $('#<%=PanelAddToList.ClientID%>').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true });
    // $('#<%=PanelAddToList.ClientID%> .List-Add').click(function () { __doPostBack('<%=BtnAddToList.UniqueID%>', ''); });
    $('#<%=PanelAddToList.ClientID%> .dialog-button-cancel').click(function () { $('#<%=PanelAddToList.ClientID%>').dialog('close'); });
    dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
});
```

This is contained in a usercontrol which has PanelAddToList in it. This control works on some pages using IIS but on others it will cause an exception on the 'var dlg =' ... line.
 If i switch back to using cassini it all works normally.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Is jQuery UI loading before your code example runs?

Comment: It does seem to be. When debugging in firebug it is available in scripts, and JQuery UI is loaded in masterpage, which is also used by the pages where the controls do work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if jquery load before not because this type of error occur when they did not find any object.
i think in you case **dialog** have some error, page can't find dialog method or arguments..

Comment: Jquery UI is loaded in the masterpage that is the master to all pages on the site - including those where the control does work and does not. Also the exact same code works when running the development server. Thanks

Comment: yah today i face same problem for auto complete,use letest jquery UI and check stylesheet too, and check where something crash with it or not and one more thing Ajax and jquery conflict sometime to create object with noconflict  and check

Comment: I have added "<script src=" ... tags to the pages and controls that are casuing problems and it now works, thanks for your help.        Not sure why some script cannot use .js files loaded in the masterpage and some can or why it all works using the dev server. From what i can tell my site is now loading mulitple copies of jquery